# Parsing a Variable from Form to Function

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a small aplication which consists of a form, which gets the current logged on user's username, has an input textbox, and a button to submit to a function. I want the username & textbox input (6 numeric digits) to base parsed to the function called by clicking the button. I can currently get the textbox input to parse using the below code.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim Input As Integer
Input = Integer.Parse(Textbox1.Text)
<Do stuff>
End Sub
```

But I can't seem to get the username to pass. In the form I have

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Dim currentADUser As System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal
currentADUser = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current
Dim LogonName As String = currentADUser.SamAccountName
End Sub
```

and I've tried parsing to the function using the below:

```
Dim LogonName As String
LogonName = String.Parse(LogonName.Text)
```

but this errors with:

> *'Parse' is not a member of 'String'.*

How do I parse varaibles in the form to the function? I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: There is no need to parse `LogonName.Text` As `Textbox.Text` is of `type string`.

Comment: So how would I call the variable? If I just have the below, LogonName is blank:

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Input As Integer
        Dim LogonName As String
        Input = Integer.Parse(Testbox1.Text)
        MsgBox(LogonName)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to do. Here's my input.

Just add the logic to get the username into the button click event

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Input As Integer
    Input = Integer.Parse(Textbox1.Text)

    Dim currentADUser As System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal
    currentADUser = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current
    Dim LogonName As String = currentADUser.SamAccountName

    <Do stuff>
End Sub
```

If you use the same logic elsewhere, create a function

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Input As Integer
    Input = Integer.Parse(Textbox1.Text)
    Dim LogonName As String = GetLogonName()

    <Do stuff>
End Sub

Private Function GetLogonName() As String
    Dim currentADUser As System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal
    currentADUser = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current
    Return currentADUser.SamAccountName
End Function
```